# Llamar un metodo y que retorne un arraylist Java

Tags: java

Buen día, estoy creando un método reporte, donde recibe un array de números y retornara otro array de 3 numero con el total de numero que hay en el array, el numero máximo que hay en el array y el mínimo.

Al momento de llamarlo y probarlo no me retorna nada. Realmente no se que estaré haciendo o llamando mal.

Main

```
public static void main(String[] args) {


        int[] numeros = {1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10};
        reporte(numeros);


    }
```

metodo reporte

```
public static int[] reporte(int[] numeros) {
        int[] resultado = new int[3];
        int mayor = 0;
        int menor = 0;
        int promedio = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i < numeros.length; i++) {
            if (numeros[i] > mayor) {
                mayor = numeros[i];
            }
            if (numeros[i] < menor) {
                menor = numeros[i];
            }
            promedio = promedio + numeros[i];
        }
        resultado[0] = mayor;
        resultado[1] = menor;
        resultado[2] = promedio / numeros.length;
        return resultado;
    }
```

Al momento de correrlo, no me muestra nada...

Comment: tu método regresa un array ,pero como lo muestras o donde lo estas haciendo???

Comment: @Dramaturgo Al momento de poner ```System.out.println(reporte(numeros));``` me muestra esto como resultado [I@76ed5528

Comment: debes iterar como lo haces dentro de tu metodo para acceder a cada valor dentro del array y mostrarlo  for (int i = 0; i < reporte(numeros).length; i++){
   System.out.println(reporte(numeros)[i]);
}

Comment: Lo realice, pero al momento de tener le array final, ya ahora si no me esta mostrando un array de 3 numero si no esto [I@76ed5528.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Debes iterar para acceder a cada valor y mostrarlo haciendo uso de print, lo otro es que tu segundo `if` nunca se cumplirá por que ningún valor de tu array es menor que `0` podes solucionarlo dándole el valor de cualquier numero guardado en tu array

```
public class Main{
public static int[] reporte(int[] numeros) {
        int[] resultado = new int[3];
        int mayor = 0;
        int menor = numeros[0];
        int promedio = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i < numeros.length; i++) {
            if (numeros[i] > mayor) {
                mayor = numeros[i];
            }
            if (numeros[i] < menor ) {
                menor = numeros[i];
            }
            promedio = promedio + numeros[i];
        }
        resultado[0] = mayor;
        resultado[1] = menor;
        resultado[2] = promedio / numeros.length;
        return resultado;
    }
public static void main(String[] args) {
    
 int[] numeros = {3, 2, 1, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10};

int [] reporteObtenido=reporte(numeros);

for (int i = 0; i < reporteObtenido.length; i++){
   System.out.println(reporteObtenido[i]);
} 
    
}

}
```

Comment: Gracias caballero, ahora entendí un poco mas, pero igualmente estoy notando que mi código tiene problemas, porque el total de números no me esta arrojando el que es

Comment: un dato adicional un array o también llamado matriz es muy diferente del concepto ArrayList ;)

Comment: Muchas gracias, ahora si entiendo porque lo que busco aparece distinto...